# Queries in Laravel - Equivalent to left join

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Currently this is my laravel query

```
    $response['appointMent'] = $this->appointment->where('user_id', Auth::guard('user')->user()->id)
    ->whereIn('status', array('Sched', 'Going', 'Request Appointment'))
    ->whereDate('set_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))
    ->with(['company'])
    ->with(['applicant'])
    ->with(['job'])
    ->with(['user'])->get();
```

But unfortunately, I would also like to get the connected data between the company and the user table, user_id for company and id for user

this is the table company table:
[image]

and the user table
[image]

How to I connect the user under the company array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to make a relationship for the company with the user like so**

Company Model

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Company::class,'user_id');
}
```

**And your query will become**

```
response['appointMent'] = $this->appointment->where('user_id', Auth::guard('user')->user()->id)
                ->whereIn('status', array('Sched', 'Going', 'Request Appointment'))
                ->whereDate('set_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))
                ->with(['company.user','applicant','job'])->get();
```

*Now the user relationship will be inside company*

OR the reverse will be
User Model

```
public function company()
{
   return $this->hasOne(User::class); //Or hasMany depends on your needs
}
```

Then the following query will be changed to

```
response['appointMent'] = $this->appointment->where('user_id', Auth::guard('user')->user()->id)
                ->whereIn('status', array('Sched', 'Going', 'Request Appointment'))
                ->whereDate('set_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))
                ->with(['user.company','applicant','job'])->get();
```

Comment: I've been tweaking the code a little and I just cracked it! thanks!!

Comment: Enjoy your day :)